# I am creating a MCQ, I want to make other options disable if any one is clicked I can't use id so I give class names

Tags: javascript, html

[image]**I am creating a MCQ, I want to make other options disable if any one is clicked I can't use id so I give class names.**
It can be done by using id but I need to use class as there will be multiple questions and options.

```
document.getElementById(id).style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```

But I need to dissable it by class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
   <th colspan="2">Q. Who is known as the father of C Language ?</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td id="q1o1" class="q1c" onclick="wrong(this.id)">&emsp;A.Sosling</td>
            <td id="q1o2" class="q1c" onclick="wrong(this.id)">&emsp;B.Vjarne Stroustrup</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td id="q1o3" class="q1c" onclick="correct(this.id)">&emsp;C.Dennis Ritchie</td>
            <td id="q1o4" class="q1c" onclick="wrong(this.id)">&emsp;D.Sujeet Arya</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <th colspan="2">Q.What is the default return type of main() in C ?</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td id="q2o1" onclick="wrong(this.id)">&emsp;A.void</td>
            <td id="q2o2" onclick="correct(this.id)">&emsp;B.int</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td id="q2o3" onclick="wrong(this.id)">&emsp;C.float</td>
            <td id="q2o4" onclick="wrong(this.id)">&emsp;D.char</td>
        </tr>
 </table>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function correct(id){
            document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor="green";
            document.getElementById(id).style.color="white";    
        }
        function wrong(id){
            document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor="red";
            document.getElementById(id).style.color="white";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Made Separate *Table* for Each Answer.
> - Bind `Click event` on *TD* of Answer *Table*.
> - First `Click` on Answer *Table*'s *TD*, `Unbind` all Sibling *TD*.

```js
$('.answer tr td').on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).closest('table').find("td").unbind();
  table = $(this).closest('table');
  table.find("td[value='correct']").attr("style", "background-color:green;color:white;");
  color = $(this).attr('value') == "correct" ? "green" : "red";
  $(this).attr("style", `background-color:${color};color:white;`);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Q. Who is known as the father of C Language ?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="answer table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td value=wrong>&emsp;A.Sosling</td>
          <td value=wrong>&emsp;B.Vjarne Stroustrup</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td value=correct>&emsp;C.Dennis Ritchie</td>
          <td value=wrong>&emsp;D.Sujeet Arya</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&emsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Q.What is the default return type of main() in C ?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table class="answer table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td value=wrong>&emsp;A.void</td>
          <td value=correct>&emsp;B.int</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td value=wrong>&emsp;C.float</td>
          <td value=wrong>&emsp;D.char</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by using id but i need to use class as there will be multiple questions and options

```
document.getElementById(id).style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```